# Is it possible to set by fluid a argument that the typo3 backend uses as input

Tags: typo3, fluid

In the typo3 template I'm using the following line to get the last 5 added items from the backend and this works.

```
 <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.lastaddeditmes" />
```

Only the number of item I want to have it flexible and set in the fluid template. So for example like below where the qty is set to three, is this possible?

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.lastaddeditmes(3)" />
```

Comment: Have no idea what are you asking about

Comment: I use this lib with last addeditems for different domain. In one domain I want for instance the 5 last items and the other 3. This quantity number I want to set in the template. The qty var needs to be send back to the typo3 backend so the correct number of items are retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in the view, instead you can make a copy of `lib.lastaddeditmes` in TypoScript and then use it in other place like:

```
lib.lastaddeditmesOnlyThree < lib.lastaddeditmes
lib.lastaddeditmesOnlyThree.someSetting.items = 3
```

and in view:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.lastaddeditmesOnlyThree" />
```

Remember that TypoScript is just a configuration syntax (not programming language) so it shouldn't give you any huge performance drop.